# Filtering using RecordType using GetSelected()

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a Visualforce page used to close cases using a list view button, certain case records should be set to a different close status than others when the button is pressed, unfortunately it appears that `getSelected()` doesn't include record type values to filter. Is there something I'm missing that can allow me to filter off record type when applying changes en masse to cases via `getSelected()`?

```java
public with sharing class CloseCaseExtensionMulti {
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;

    public CloseCaseExtensionMulti(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    
    public PageReference doLoad() {
        List<sObject> cases = controller.getSelected();
        
        for(sObject thisCase : cases) {
            if(thisCase.RecordTypeId == '0120z000000cYd0AAE'){
                thisCase.put('status','Solved (with no response)');
            }
            else{
                thisCase.put('status', 'Closed');
            }
        }
        
        PageReference rval;
        try {
            rval = controller.save();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return System.currentPageReference();
        }
                
        return rval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record(s) you get from a `StandardController` or `StandardSetController` only contain the fields that are rendered in your Visualforce page (as I recall, adding something like `html-style="visibility:hidden"` or `rendered="{![something that evaluates to false here]}"` causes Salesforce to not automatically pull in that field).

The general workaround to that is to simply use the standard(Set)Controller to gather record Ids, and then perform a SOQL query to access the field(s) that you want.